# Letting users to access to their own folder - multi site in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, vb.net, routes, authorization

Looking to address multi sites on one physical path.

Some of sites has Https and some of them hasn't, so with current code I able to force them to https or not.

On case there is "images" folder, how could I access them, just to own folder. For example there is DomainId for each site and images goes to save like: */images/DomainId/*
So on case `DomainId=3` , I should let users to access only on */images/3/* physical path.

**How about providing .config file on each folder, and accessing specific domain to that folder.**

```
public class SiteInfo
{
public long DomainId;
public bool HasHTTPS;
}

protected void Application_BeginRequest(Object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  string domain = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory;
  SiteInfo objSiteInfo=objEntity.Domains.FirstOrDefault(c=>c.domainName==domain);

if(objSiteInfo.HasHTTPS)
{
  switch (Request.Url.Scheme)
  {
    case "https":
      Response.AddHeader("Strict-Transport-Security", "max-age=300");
      break;
    case "http":
      var path = "https://" + Request.Url.Host + Request.Url.PathAndQuery;
      Response.Status = "301 Moved Permanently";
      Response.AddHeader("Location", path);
      break;
  }
}

//How about accessing to images folder?

}
```

Comment: It's probably be easier to have GUIDs for users instead of ints so your folders are like `/images/e0063625-b123-4e38-882b-64a1f689b22e/` - the chances of someone guessing a random guid are very low, so you just make sure you don't tell user B the guid of user A

Comment: @CaiusJard you are right and for now it's like: /images/DomainId/random_string. But It's would be awful on case someone copy paste the url to another domain. Maybe I should take it easy and skip it.